# How to unit test .ejs files that produced by Express server?

Tags: unit-testing, express, jestjs, ejs, testing-library

I have a simple http Express server that serves a couple of routes like home, about, news, etc.

For each of routes, I use `res.render('some_ejs_file')`, to render a html page with `.ejs` extension. each page has a `.js` file script, and I just wonder how can I render the `.ejs` files to run the proper js file and render the page to test it?

I installed the `@testing-library` and  `jest` and here is my `home.test.js` file:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

const html = fs.readFileSync(
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../views/pages/index.ejs'),
  'utf8'
)

let dom
let container

describe('Home page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    dom = new JSDOM(html, { runScripts: 'dangerously' })
    container = dom.window.document.body
  })

  test('should show 1', () => {
    console.log('>>> ', container.querySelector('header'))
    expect(container.querySelector('h1')).not.toBeNull()
    expect(1).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

But the issue is that when I `querySelect` something from `container`, it always returns `null` and I can't proceed in testing step. What am I doing wrong, and how can I get proper testing experience with `.ejs` composed markup files?

Here is my jest config file:

```js
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['regenerator-runtime/runtime'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ejs', 'ejx'],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Because we need to run and serve `.ejs` to test, first we need to render the ejs file, after looking some solutions inside `ejs` package documentations, I figured out that I might be able to render the ejs file first by this function:

```js
ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function(err, str){
    // str => Rendered HTML string
});
```

As you can see it will give you a `string` of the ejs rendered file, then with that you can pass the result into `JSDOM` and you have your DOM to Interact with in your testing environment!

Here was the final solution that I came up with:

```js
import moment from 'moment'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import ejs from 'ejs'

const targetFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../views/pages/index.ejs')

ejs.renderFile(targetFile, function (err, str) {
  if (str) {
    let dom
    let container

    describe('Home page', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        dom = new JSDOM(str, { moment }, { runScripts: 'dangerously' })
        container = dom.window.document.body
      })

      test('should show 1', () => {
        console.log('>>> ', container.querySelector('h1').textContent)
        expect(container.querySelector('h1')).not.toBeNull()
        expect(1).toBe(1)
      })
    })
  }
})
```

I am happy to hear if I'm doing some thing wrong!

Comment: Can you explain what is 'moment' please?

Comment: i use moment js inside of my .ejs file, so i need to pass it inside the dom in order to not get error that moment is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Amdev did a great job (thank you) laying this out but I adjusted a little as Jest was failing to detect a test when the describe() and test() were nested.  The following refactored code may help others.

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import path from "path";
import ejs from "ejs";
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
import fs from "fs";

const targetFile = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.ejs");

describe("[ROOT]", () => {
    test("should load header section", () => {
        ejs.renderFile(targetFile, function (err, htmlString) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (htmlString) {
                let dom;
                let container;
                beforeEach(() => {
                    dom = new JSDOM(htmlString, {}, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
                    container = dom.window.document.body;
                });
                console.log(dom);
                expect(getByText(/MY TEXT/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
            }
        });
    });
});
```